# Binding an eventlistener to a deep-nested generated div

Tags: jquery

I am relatively new to JQuery.

My use case is this: I retrieve an array of JSON objects, and then want to create a list of bootstrap media elements from these. To each element, I want to associate an "add" button which will result in some logic for that user being generated.

My code looks like this:

```
              $.each(result, function(index, user) {
                  resultContainer
                  .append(
                    '<div class="media">' +
                        '<a class="pull-left" href=' + Routing.generate('show_profile', { user_id: user.id }) + '>' +
                            '<img src=/uploads/images/' + user.picture + ' ' + 'height="32px" width="32px" />' +
                        '</a>' +
                        '<div class="media-body">' +
                            '<h4 class="media-heading">' + user.firstname + ' ' + user.lastname + '</h4>' + user.description
                  )
                  .append(
                        '<div class="btn-group pull-right">' +
                            '<a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Add</a>' +
                        '</div>'
                  ).on('click', function(){
                      alert(index); 
                      alert(user);
                  })
                  .append(
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>'
                    );
              });
```

The problem with this is that the listener seems to get bound to the top DOM element (resultContainer), so all listeners respond as soon as I click on anything.

I understand that I could possibly solve this by generating each DOM element by itself, connecting listeners where appropriate, and then nesting them within each other using JQuery. However, is there a simpler way to do achieve this using only a single chain of methods calls, like I intended to do above?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
                $.each(result, function(index, user) {
                  resultContainer
                  .append(
                    '<div class="media">' +
                        '<a class="pull-left" href=' + Routing.generate('show_profile', { user_id: user.id }) + '>' +
                            '<img src=/uploads/images/' + user.picture + ' ' + 'height="32px" width="32px" />' +
                        '</a>' +
                        '<div class="media-body">' +
                            '<h4 class="media-heading">' + user.firstname + ' ' + user.lastname + '</h4>' + user.description
                  )
                  .append(
                        '<div class="btn-group pull-right">' +
                            '<a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Add</a>' +
                        '</div>'
                  )
                  .append(
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>'
                   ).filter('.btn')
                    .on('click', function(){
                      alert(index); 
                      alert(user);
                  });
              });
```

Comment: Does not work for me unforuntately - now there is no listener at all present (checked this with the Chrome dev tools as well).

Answer (score 0):

On the call to `jQuery.on`, you can specify a selector as the second argument. You may want to add some distinguishing attribute/class to your add button, like:

```
<a data-add-button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Add</a>
```

Then, use that when binding your listener:

```
.on("click", "[data-add-button]", function() {
   // ...
});
```